# Type Error occurred when creating object in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.4, magento2.4.1

I am creating the custom module to Log the custom module logs **Info, Error** to custom table and the module working. But when I compile the module getting below error.

```
/var/www/html/var/log/exception.log
[2020-12-21 10:43:14] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: 
Learning\LoggerModule\Model\ResourceModel\CustomLogger\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to 
Learning\LoggerModule\Model\ResourceModel\CustomLogger\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface or be null, 
string given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 
{"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Type Error occurred when creating object: 
Learning\\LoggerModule\\Model\\ResourceModel\\CustomLogger\\Collection\\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to 
Learning\\LoggerModule\\Model\\ResourceModel\\CustomLogger\\Collection\\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\AdapterInterface or be null, 
string given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 at 
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131)"} []
```

The Collection class as below

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Learning\LoggerModule\Model\ResourceModel\CustomLogger;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Learning\LoggerModule\Model\CustomLogger;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomLogger::class,
            \Learning\LoggerModule\Model\ResourceModel\CustomLogger::class
        );
    }
    
}
```

Please suggest us to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

May be you added public construct before.

Just try with removing generated folder

> **rm -rf generated/***

> **php bin/magento c:f**